# Cambio de color de fondo automatico

Tags: html, css3

tengo este código

```
.description {
            padding-bottom: 4%;
            text-align: center;
            animation: back_animate 25s infinite linear;
@keyframes back_animate {
            0% {
                 background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #23A6D5, #23D5AB);
               }
           10% {
                 background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #23A6D5, #EE7752);
               }
           20% {
                 background: linear-gradient(-10deg, #23A6D5, #E73C7E);
               }
```

lo que hace es cambiarme el color de fondo de forma automática, pero al cambiar de color lo hace de golpe, le puse transition 1s; para que al cambiar de color lo hiciera de forma lenta pero no me sirvió.

que me recomiendan hacer

gracias

Comment: creo que no es posible animar así un degradado. lo que se suele hacer es animar la posición del fondo, como en este ejemplo: https://codepen.io/P1N2O/pen/pyBNzX

Comment: justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Te falta definir: `animation-duration: 1s;` donde '1s' es un segundo...

Comment: Ya tiene la duración definida en 25 segundos, no es ese el problema